# How to update 'enableNonSslPort' field of redis cache using azure cli?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-redis-cache

I tried the below command to update the enableNonSslPort field to true of redis cache named 'emp' which has 'group1' has resource group.

az redis update --name 'emp' --resource-group 'group1' --enableNonSslPort 'true'

I m getting error,
Try this: 'az redis update --name  --resource-group  --vm-size '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [az redis update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/redis?view=azure-cli-latest#az_redis_update) cmdlet does not have an option for enabling/disabling non SSL port:

```
az redis update [--add]
                [--force-string]
                [--ids]
                [--name]
                [--remove]
                [--resource-group]
                [--set]
                [--sku {Basic, Premium, Standard}]
                [--subscription]
                [--vm-size {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]
```

You can use [az create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/redis?view=azure-cli-latest#az_redis_create) command to do this (*you cannot update non SSL port settings of  Azure Redis cache using CLI*):

```
az redis create --location
                --name
                --resource-group
                --sku {Basic, Premium, Standard}
                --vm-size {c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}
                [--enable-non-ssl-port]
                [--minimum-tls-version {1.0, 1.1, 1.2}]
                [--redis-configuration]
                [--replicas-per-master]
                [--shard-count]
                [--static-ip]
                [--subnet-id]
                [--subscription]
                [--tags]
                [--tenant-settings]
                [--zones {1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: Yes, this answers my question. I just wanted to make sure whether we can update the 'enableNonSslPort' field.